# How to update constructor values in haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to update the values of a constructor given a value.
For example say I have the constructor:

```
data Submission =
  Submission { session :: String,
               quizName :: String,
               student :: String
             } deriving (Eq,Show)
```

I have a function called `update` for example. this is the type signature:

```
update (String, String)-> Maybe Submission -> Maybe Submission
```

Given a tuple of strings where fst is the name of the key and snd is the output we want, update will update the given Submission constructor if there is nothing in that key.

So far, I have done this:

```
update (String, String)-> Maybe Submission -> Maybe Submission 
update x y 
   | fst x == "session" && Submission {session = Nothing } = return Submission {session = snd x}
   | fst x = "quizName" && Submission {quizName = Nothing} = return Submission {quizName = snd x}
   | fst x = "student" && Submission {student = Nothing} = return Submission {student = snd x}
   | otherwise = y
```

Basically, given a tuple and the constructor, if the fst value of the tuple equals to a key and the key is empty it will then update y. We do this for all keys. Otherwise if keys already have values we just return the constructor back.

Also would an empty constructor just look like this?

```
Submission {student = "",quizName = "",student =""}
```

Comment: You say: `session :: String` but then you compare the string `session` with `Nothing` in `session = Nothing`. This is not possible and a problem that you need to fix.

Comment: Since you already give names to your tuple why not use them in the code as well? Use `update (key, val)` instead of `update x y` and replace `fst x` with `key` and `snd x` with `val`.

Comment: Am I crazy or should this just be three different functions? When are you going to have a piece of data, but you don't know *until runtime* whether it's the name of a quiz or of a student??

Answer (score 2):

When possible, use patterns instead of guards. Patterns give values to variables, guards (usually) do not.

```
update :: (String, String)-> Maybe Submission -> Maybe Submission 
update ("session", y)  (Just s@(Submission{session = Nothing })) =
   Just (s{session = y})
update ("quizName", y) (Just s@(Submission{quizName = Nothing })) =
   Just (s{quizName = y})
...
update _ ms = ms
```

Note the pattern `Just s@(...)`. This checks that the argument is a `Just` whole contents match against the `...` pattern. The `s@` part also binds the variable `s` to the contents. In this way later on we can use `s{ field = value}` to update only one field of the record value.

Answer (score 0):

Although probably overkill for a (toy-)example, an idea could be to make use of lenses. We then install the [**`lens`** package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens), and then make lenses for the `Submission` type:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens.Combinators (makeLenses)

data Submission = Submission
  { _session :: String,
    _quizName :: String,
    _student :: String
  }
  deriving (Eq, Show)

makeLenses ''Submission
```

Then the update is just:

```
import Control.Lens.Setter(set)

update :: (String, String) -> Maybe Submission -> Maybe Submission
update = fmap . uncurry go
  where
    go "session" = set session
    go "quizName" = set quizName
    go "student" = set student
    go _ = const id
```

this will then set the corresponding field, regardless what the original value was. The fields in the `Submission` are not of type `Maybe String`, and thus will always have a string as value, perhaps an empty one, but a string.

If you want to make these `Maybe String`s, we can refactor this to:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Lens.Combinators (makeLenses)
import Control.Lens.Setter (set)

data Submission = Submission {_session :: Maybe String, _quizName :: Maybe String, _student :: Maybe String} deriving (Eq, Show)

makeLenses ''Submission
```

then we can work with:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<|>))
import Control.Lens.Setter (over)

update :: (String, String) -> Maybe Submission -> Maybe Submission
update = fmap . uncurry go
  where
    go "session" = go' session
    go "quizName" = go' quizName
    go "student" = go' student
    go _ = const id
    go' s v = over s (<|> Just v)
```

this will then only update the value in case we set it on a `Submission` object that has `Nothing` for that field we aim to update.